# How to Create a Test Suite in Salesforce Using ANT Without Using the Developer Console?

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, test-automation, test-suite

I'm looking to set up a **comprehensive test suite in Salesforce** using **ANT**, and I want to perform all the tasks without relying on the Developer Console. Can someone provide guidance or a step-by-step approach on how to achieve this?

I've been using Salesforce's Developer Console for testing, but I'd like to automate the process as much as possible through ANT scripts. Specifically, I'd like to know how to:

1. Create a test suite using ANT.
2. Add individual test classes to the suite.
3. Execute the test suite through ANT.

Any code snippets, sample ANT build files, or tips on best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run all tests, just use the `testLevel` of `RunLocalTests`. If you really want to build a suite, just look at the [ApexTestSuite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_apextestsuite.htm) metadata API. You can build the appropriate XML file, and then use deploy.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know this option!

My use case is as follows:
I have a list of classes to validate and a list of test classes that I want to launch, I would like to have as a result the outcome of the individual tests (success/failure), and the coverage of the classes present in the set of classes to be validated.

Does this technique handle my use case, or does it return coverage of all the classes it touches, even outside the set to be validated?

Comment: The peculiarity of my use-case is that for each package to be deployed this set varies, and is not pre-determined.
If I understood this solution correctly, the sets must be developed first, by hand, and then launched.

Instead, I would like to launch the tests from ant, and have the results of the tests, and the coverage of the files in the package, without performing any compilation of the tested classes, those are compiled a little at a time as soon as they are committed, I want to run the tests during the Night

Comment: @EmanueleAlfano Any classes/triggers executed will be reported when running a subset of tests. The XML file for a Test Suite can be built by a script and deployed. It sounds like you don't want the Test Suite to exist after execution, so `testLevel` of `RunSpecifiedTests` is probably a better alternative. You can deploy a zero-member `package.xml` and combine with `testLevel` to avoid code deployment, or you can use `ApexTestQueueItem` from the Tooling API to specify tests without a metadata deployment at all.

Comment: Currently the solution we use is `testLevel` of `RunSpecifiedTests`, with the metadata to be deployed in the package.xml (even if already deployed in the past).
The problem with this methodology is that if a resource creates a conflict, during the validation phase, the system does not try to execute the remaining test classes. We have to manually revert that resource, to eliminate the problem, when at this stage of development it would be more useful to know that that resource fails, but also that the others pass or fail the tests and coverage (with a view to development for release)